# Android IntentService stays in Eclipse's Thread list

Tags: android, eclipse, intentservice

I noticed that in Eclipse thread tool, a bunch of IntentService stays in Native state as long as the app is running. Should them not be garbage collected and disappear from this list ?

For example :

```
1   13677   Native  2786    1142    main    
*2  13680   VmWait  567 39  GC  
*3  13682   VmWait  0   0   Signal Catcher  
*4  13683   Runnable    65  149 JDWP    
*5  13684   VmWait  67  51  Compiler    
*6  13685   Wait    3   0   ReferenceQueueDaemon    
*7  13686   Wait    17  8   FinalizerDaemon 
*8  13687   TimedWait   2   0   FinalizerWatchdogDaemon 
9   13688   Native  94  32  Binder_1    
10  13689   Native  72  50  Binder_2    
11  13707   Wait    0   0   AsyncTask #1    
12  13727   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
13  13804   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
14  13825   Wait    4   4   AsyncTask #2    
15  13838   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
16  13871   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
17  14060   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
18  14477   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
19  14514   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
20  14538   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
21  14554   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
22  14569   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
23  14593   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
24  14616   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
25  14632   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
26  14635   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
27  14659   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
28  14666   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
29  14686   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
30  14701   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
31  14712   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
32  14728   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
33  14743   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
34  14755   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
35  14771   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
36  14794   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
37  14810   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
38  14813   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
39  14836   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
40  14839   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
41  14855   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
42  14879   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
43  14895   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
44  14898   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
45  14921   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
46  14924   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
47  14940   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
48  14955   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
49  14966   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
50  14982   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]    
51  15005   Native  0   0   IntentService[WebserviceService]
```

Basically, this IntentService is using a HandlerThread, it add an object (given in the data intent) in a queue, and it process each item added in the queue using a handler

```
public class WebserviceService extends IntentService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("WebserviceService");
    mHandlerThread.start();

    mServiceLooper = mHandlerThread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);

    mQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<QueueWebservice>();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onStart("+intent.getAction()+")");

    mQueue.add(new QueueWebservice(intent));
    mServiceHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");

    if(mServiceLooper != null){
        mServiceLooper.quit();
        mServiceLooper = null;
    }

    if(mHandlerThread != null){
        mHandlerThread.quit();
        mHandlerThread = null;
    }

}

private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            final QueueWebservice item = mQueue.take();
            onHandleIntent(item.getIntent());
            if (mQueue.isEmpty()) {
                WebserviceService.this.stopSelf();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
    // My main job
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");

    if(mServiceLooper != null){
        mServiceLooper.quit();
        mServiceLooper = null;
    }

    if(mHandlerThread != null){
        mHandlerThread.quit();
        mHandlerThread = null;
    }

}
}
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Please put the service class full. Want to see what you extends.

Comment: I extends IntentService

Comment: IntentService can not stop once started. Once it finished it work then automatically stops. So your stop call doesn't work.

Comment: @AnandMakwana Ok, so my stopSelf() is useless, but it should be garbage collected, or at list be deleted from my list in Eclipse, no ?

Comment: Yeah, once service finishes its task then it automatically destroyed by system and garbage collected.

Comment: @AnandMakwana So, how do explain that it is still visible in the Thread list in Eclipse ?

Comment: I have run into the same issue, you ever figure out what was going on?